# vega: Can I create marks using information coming from two datasets?

Tags: visualization, vega

I would like to create some marks, where the information of the size comes from one dataset and the information of the color comes from another dataset.

Is this possible?

Or can I update created marks (created with dataset 1) by using information from a second dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it.

You can use [lookup transform](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/lookup/) provided there is a lookup key in both datasets.

In this [example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-C0k4gLIq5OvnBwHDu5zp13U4gPSHqnoezrN2quBeKuq6PiqukbBytq2A62yMs+2yfAqDRQF+6cYeBIC9FSBwWgVJH1S7OKEswpzvts5Hni9Cm3tInBUM6-rjtmkBhrOmQnxfOkv2vFRKDk7JFq0ygHRkVbcrOgrNrZhl0E-b9ub2nK2AbBtUg9ABaaogKuawPTWhGpbbTmf0oeWWvuhwAHkGigOhfkqhQb3QhBtAAXld7QZa538Nzxy6PjJsNpSu6UgA), 'category' is the key that performs lookup transform